# Inserting large binary blobs with aiomysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, aio-mysql

I'm trying to insert a large binary blolb (column type `LONGBLOB`) into a local mariadb instance using `aiomysql` version 0.0.20 (https://pypi.org/project/aiomysql/).

I pass the blob inside a python `str` object via `INSERT` using the `%` syntax: `execute('INSERT INTO blah VALUES (%s)', (large_blolb))`.

The blob is rather large (~500million character, so probably ~0.6 to 1GB), but certainly bellow the 4GB limit of `LONGBLOB`

The insert seems to fail due to network errors... How may I go about doing this ? Is there an option doing with with aiomysql ? What would be the easiest async alternative (e.g. starting an async sub-process and having mariadb read from a file)

Comment: Did you check the value of `max_allowed_packet` server variable?

Comment: Did not know that was an option, might well be the issue I'm encountering, will report back when I check.